# Do we have an API to get Test Cycle Summary in Qtest?

Tags: api, testing, reporting, summary, qtest

Do we have an API in Qtest that can provide summary of test cycle execution ?

E.g.  Passed: 23 Failed: 7 Unexecuted: 10 Running: 2

Need this data for generating report in our consolidated reporting tool along with data from some other sources.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that gives exactly what you ask for, but you could use the API calls below to create it yourself.

You can get the status of all test runs in a project using

```
GET /api/v3/projects/{projectId}/test-runs/execution-statuses
```

Or, to get results from a specific test cycle, first find all the test runs in that cycle using

```
/api/v3/projects/{projectId}/test-runs?parentId={testCycleID}&parentType=test-cycle
```

(append *&expand=descendants* to find test runs in containers under the test cycle)

and then get the results of each run individually using

```
/api/v3/projects/{projectId}/test-runs/{testRunId}/test-logs/last-run
```

See https://qtest.dev.tricentis.com/